# Is there an out of the box (de)serializer for UUID in json4s?

Tags: json4s

I'm having a problem very similar to what's described here: [Combining type and field serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277713/combining-type-and-field-serializers)

```
case class(id: Option[UUID], otherValue:String, … )
```

The answer to [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277713/combining-type-and-field-serializers) would allow me to write my own format, but I'm curious if there is already a format for UUID hiding somewhere in json4s. I'd guessed that the right import would solve this issue for UUID, and I was a bit surprised not to find anything.

Did I miss it, or is it not there yet?

Comment: I guess not, but I've made a pull request: https://github.com/json4s/json4s/pull/130

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since [my pull request](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/pull/130/files) was merged, there is JavaTypesSerializers.

Usage:

```
implicit lazy val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) ++ 
                            org.json4s.ext.JavaTypesSerializers.all
```

Answer (score 5):

For someone who is looking for a UUID serializer, it has been included in 3.2.11 version of json4s-ext.

Checkout this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25511897/1596111