# Can't get json4s to render my case class?

Tags: scala, json4s

I set up a SBT console like...

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
case class TagOptionOrNull(tag: String, optionUuid: Option[java.util.UUID], uuid: java.util.UUID)
val t1 = new TagOptionOrNull("t1", Some(java.util.UUID.randomUUID), java.util.UUID.randomUUID)
val t2 = new TagOptionOrNull("t2", None, null)
```

I'm trying to see json4s's behavior around null vs Option[UUID].  But I can't figure out the invocation to get it to make my case class a String of JSON.

```
scala> implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
formats: org.json4s.DefaultFormats.type = org.json4s.DefaultFormats$@614275d5

scala> compact(render(t1))
<console>:23: error: type mismatch;
 found   : TagOptionOrNull
 required: org.json4s.JValue
    (which expands to)  org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue
       compact(render(t1))
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Serialization.write`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#serialization) should be able to serialise case class like so

```
import org.json4s.native.Serialization.write
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats ++ JavaTypesSerializers.all
println(write(t1))
```

which should output

```
{"tag":"t1","optionUuid":"95645021-f60c-4708-8bf3-9d5609559fdb","uuid":"19cc4979-5836-4edf-aedd-dcb3e96f17d6"}
```

Note to serialise `UUID` we need [`JavaTypeSerializers`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35154397/5205022) formats from

```
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-ext" % version
```

Comment: works great, mario.  But now I don't know the difference between `render` and `write` (beyond `render` doesn't work for my simpleton use case).  `render` only works with that DSL stuff?

Comment: `render` takes `JValue` not a case class. Confusingly, render appears to take primitive values, for example, `render(List(1,2))`, however this argument is implicitly converted to `JValue` using `seq2jvalue`. For case classes, I think we need `write`.