# json4s: Deserializing specific fields with a custom serializer

Tags: json, scala, case-class, json4s

I have a case class with many members, two of which are non-primitive:

```
import com.twitter.util.Duration
case class Foo(
  a: Int,
  b: Int,
  ...,
  y: Int,
  z: Int,
  timeoutSeconds: Duration,
  runtimeMinutes: Duration)
```

I'd like to deserialize the following JSON into an instance of this case class:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  // ...
  "y": 42,
  "z": 43,
  "timeoutSeconds": 30,
  "runtimeMinutes": 12,
}
```

Normally, I would just write `json.extract[Foo]`.  However, I get an obvious `MappingException` with that because of `timeoutSeconds` and `runtimeMinutes`.

I've looked at `FieldSerializer`, which allows field transforms on the AST.  However, it's insufficient because it *only* allows AST transforms.

I've also looked at extending `CustomSerializer[Duration]`, but there's no way to introspect which JSON key is being dealt with (`timeoutSeconds` or `runtimeMinutes`).

I could also try extending `CustomSerializer[Foo]`, but then I will have a lot of boilerplate code for extracting values for `a`, `b`, ..., `z`.

Ideally, I need something that takes `PartialFunction[JField, T]` as a deserializer so that I could just write:

```
{
  case ("timeoutSeconds", JInt(timeout) => timeout.seconds
  case ("runtimeMinutes", JInt(runtime) => runtime.minutes
}
```

and rely on case class deserialization for the remaining parameters.  Is such a construction possible in json4s?

Note this is similar to [Combining type and field serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277713/combining-type-and-field-serializers), except I additionally want the type deserialization to differ based on the JSON key.

Comment: As a workaround, you could serialize all your `Duration`s in seconds then update the `runtimeMinutes` field.

Comment: i.e., Add a CustomSerializer[Duration] that always does seconds, then `orig.copy(runtimeMinutes = orig.runtimeMinutes / 60)`.  That would work, but is a little hacky.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Using Json.NET

```
string json = @"{
```

"a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  // ...
  "y": 42,
  "z": 43,
  "timeoutSeconds": 30,
  "runtimeMinutes": 12,
}";

```
BlogSites bsObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BlogSites>(json);  

Response.Write(bsObj.Name);
```

Comment: 1st create json variable having json data then Deserialize the json data afterwards write that object.Name value